# Overflow:Hidden isn't working correctly in Div

Tags: css, overflow

so, I'm new to this and I'm working on a basic redirect Tumblr theme [not important] but I have a banner which is a div box and I want to fit into an image as it would if I was using overflow:hidden. the only problem is, that command isn't working. Part of the code had to be copied and pasted, and I think something within the c/p'ed css is keeping that from working. Also, sorry in advance if my code is written terribly, again I'm new at this.

The white background/banner that says 'this blog has moved' is what I'm trying to hide so it doesn't overlap the border.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">


</HEAD>
<STYLE>


 body {background-color: #dff2f4;}



  img {
  height: 500px;
  width: 710px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 355px;
  border-width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #cbdaff;
 }


 .centered {
  font-family: 'SourceSansPro-ExtraLight';
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  color: #dadada;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50.7%;
  width: 750px ;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 7px 7px 7px 7px;




}



 @font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro-ExtraLight.ttf';
    src: url('fonts/SourceSansPro-ExtraLight.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}



</STYLE>
<BODY>

 <div class="banner">
  <div class="centered">THIS BLOG HAS MOVED</div>

 <img src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/0ec32bfc5aeafd4db56b123737224ef8/tumblr_pn6qcyuFhy1xiq9t5o2_r1_540.gif">



 </div>












</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to?

Comment: Can we see the actual and expected rendering?

Comment: @DogukanCavus I dont want the edges of the banner to overlap outside of the image, sorry if I didn't get that across in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this?

```css
body {background-color: #dff2f4;}

.img {
 background: url("https://66.media.tumblr.com/0ec32bfc5aeafd4db56b123737224ef8/tumblr_pn6qcyuFhy1xiq9t5o2_r1_540.gif");
 height: 500px;
 width: 710px;
 margin-top: 100px;
 margin-left: 355px;
 border-width: 15px;
 border-radius: 50px;
 border-style: double;
 border-color: white;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #cbdaff;
}

.centered {
 font-family: 'SourceSansPro-ExtraLight';
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 background-color: white;
 text-align: center;
 color: #dadada;
 margin-top: 50%;
 width: 750px ;
 font-size: 30px;
 letter-spacing: 10px;
 padding: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: 'SourceSansPro-ExtraLight.ttf';
 src: url('fonts/SourceSansPro-ExtraLight.ttf') format('truetype');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="img">
   <div class="centered">THIS BLOG HAS MOVED</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```